# Assimp md5 scene with animations "has no animations"

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, 3d, directx

I've been following the tutorials at [OGLdev](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html) and [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/#!Model-Loading/Assimp) to load assimp files. I can load static objects like the crysis nanosuit and the animated doom3 format model "boblampclean". The problem is that I cant get the animations from the md5 file. When I query whether the file has animations it returns 0 and other calls to get animation related things from it crash. I've tried different versions of assimp - 3.0, 3.1.1, and 3.3.3 built from vcpkg.

For example, if I run this it will return 0 although there is for sure an animation in the file. If I use the 32bit visual studio project from OGLdev it returns 1.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Assimp::Importer myImporter;
    const aiScene *m_scene = NULL;
    m_scene = myImporter.ReadFile("C:/users/bergj/desktop/obj/boblampclean.md5mesh", aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs | aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals | aiProcess_JoinIdenticalVertices | aiProcess_CalcTangentSpace);

    if (m_scene)
    {
        cout << "has anim = " << m_scene->HasAnimations() << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "no scene" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to copy the md5anim file into the same folder. Damn.